# how to get the row index in a datagrid wpf according to the button of the row pressed

Tags: .net, wpf

i have a datagrid in wpf with an edit button with each row. How do i get the rows index that is in focus i.e. the row whose edit button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

If your items are unique, you can retrieve the index with `IndexOf(item)` on your collection. So, you basically need your item and your collection, then you are good to go.

You can access the collection easily in code behind by giving your `DataGrid` a name. For the item, you can traverse the visual tree from the `Button` up to the `DataGridRow` and then use its `DataGridRow.Item` property.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Button Column">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Edit"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I assume the `DataContext` of the grid to be the items collection.

In code behind, handle the `Button_Click` event. I use a helper method to find the `DataGridRow` recursively.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = GetParent<DataGridRow>((Button)sender);
    var index = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(row.Item);
    MessageBox.Show("Index = " + index, "Clicked Value");
}

private TargetType GetParent<TargetType>(DependencyObject o)
    where TargetType : DependencyObject
{
    if (o == null || o is TargetType) return (TargetType)o;
    return GetParent<TargetType>(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o));
}
```

This should give you a messagebox, displaying the index of your column.

However, In most cases people don't actually need the index but want to access an item behind the index instead. In this case, just forget about the `IndexOf` part and just take the `row.Item` as is.